# Seeking ArcGIS Pro cheat sheet

Tags: arcgis-pro, references

Is there a cheat sheet that helps me remember where settings are hidden in ArcGIS Pro?

I am looking for a poster that I can hang next to my monitor.

Comment: https://www.esri.com/content/dam/esrisites/en-us/media/pdf/g526942-arcgis-pro-kybrd-shrtct-FINAL.pdf (Windows 10 users warning there are changes coming where copy +v will have windows button +v due to Microsoft )

Answer (score 2):

[ArcGIS Pro keyboard shortcuts](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/arcgis-pro-keyboard-shortcuts.htm) also has a link to a PDF you can print out:

> This is a complete list of keyboard shortcuts available in ArcGIS Pro
> and is updated at every software release. A PDF version can be
> downloaded from https://links.esri.com/arcgis-pro-shortcuts but may
> not include the most recent updates.